# Azure Devops kubectl task deployed image is with status ErrImagePull/ImagePullBackOff

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have created a deployment pipeline using Azure Devops through which I am building and pushing an image to Azure Container Registry.
In the next step I am deploying from ACR to an AKS cluster which I have created and attached to ACR using the following command:
az aks create -n HealthCareAKSCluster -g AKSCICDRG --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr HealthCareAKSCICDACR
Following is my yaml code:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
  imageRepository: 'patientservice'
  containerRegistry: 'healthcareakscicdacr.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: './PatientService/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  jobs:  
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Kubernetes@1
      displayName: Deploy an image to AKS
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'XXXXXXX'
        azureResourceGroup: 'AKSCICDRG'
        kubernetesCluster: 'HealthCareAKSCluster'
        command: 'apply'
        arguments: '-f patientservice.yaml'
        secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
        containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

The image is getting pushed to ACR successfully and Build step is running fine. 
[image]

Even deploy step is running fine but when I do 'kubectl get pods' in my AKS cluster I am getting the pod status as ImagePullBackOff or ErrImagePull. 
When I did 'kubectl describe pod' I am getting the following message:

> Failed to pull image "patientservice": rpc error: code = Unknown desc
>   = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for patientservice, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
>   requested access to the resource is denied

Please help as to how can I deploy a proper image.

Comment: Please share your patientservice.yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in patientservice.yaml file. I overlooked it. Previously image had only the name of the service.I added the following to the image in patientservice.yaml:

```
image: healthcareakscicdacr.azurecr.io/patientservice:latest
```

The deployment worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)